# Appending a value to return value of function range()

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I'm learning python and am studying from the book *Dive into the Python*. It says :

> The built−in `range` function returns a list of integers. In its
>   simplest form, it takes an   upper limit and returns a zero−based list
>   counting up to but not including the upper limit.

According to what it says, it returns a list. I thought that I could append a value to it with append function, but I couldn't.

```
>>> l = range(7)
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l.append(13)
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 13]
>>> l = range(7).append(13)
>>> l
```

It doesn't print anything, what's the reason?

Comment: Side note: `range` only returns a list in Python 2.x. In Python 3, you'll get an `AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'append'`

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that [`list.append`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm) operates in-place and therefore always returns `None`.

In other words, this line:

```
l = range(7).append(13)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
l = None
```

---

Note too that the example you posted proves that appending values to the list returned by `range` works as expected if you call `list.append` on its own line:

```
>>> l = range(7)
>>> l.append(13)  # Call list.append on its own line
>>> l  # And it works as expected
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 13]
>>>
```